# Is there a way to recursively load all of a project's modules in GHCi?

Tags: haskell, loading, ghci

I have a project that has several subdirectories of code, structured something like...

```
src/Main.hs
src/Module1/... # many *.hs source files, here
src/Module1/ModuleA/... # more *.hs files
src/Module2/...
```

when I run ghci, I end up doing this:

`ghci src/Module1/ModuleA/*.hs src/Module1/*.hs src/Module2/*.hs ... <and so on> ... src/*.hs`

The above command *works*, but seems really verbose when all I really want to say is *"recursively search all subdirectories and load all Haskell modules in them"*

Comment: You could let `Module1` reexport `Module1.ModuleA` and all its other submodules, and then just import `Module1`, `Module2`, etc.

Comment: Well, the problem I'm running into isn't just that the functions I want aren't available in GHCi.  I'm getting errors that say, oh, `Main.hs` requires `Module1.SomeModule`, but it wasn't loaded!  However, the source compiles fine when I run `ghc src/Main.hs`.

Comment: Well if you're using `zsh` then you could say `ghci src/**/*.hs`

Comment: @luqui's suggestion also works for people using a normal shell if they turn on globstart (`shopt -s globstar`).

Comment: or you just use [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org) and `stack ghci` :)

Comment: I am using stack.  The actual command I was using was `stack repl -- <and then all the directories>`

Comment: If you are using the command `stack repl -- <directories>` then you are almost certainly doing it wrong - the contents of those directories should be appropriately stated in your `.cabal` file, and the command should simply be `stack repl`.

Comment: "recursively search all subdirectories and load all Haskell modules in them" - just use `find` to collect all Haskell modules and put them in your `.cabal` file, if you are too lazy to manually type them out.